# Merge two tabs in Java Swing

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtabbedpane

Thank you for viewing. I'm a beginner with Java swing. I'm trying to merge two tabs in an application. The tabs are created in this way:

```
  pane=new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP, JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT);
  pane.add(panel1);
  pane.add(panel2);
```

I'd like to have the contents of **panel1** and **panel2** merged together, with **panel2** displayed underneath **panel1**. I know this may seem like a very simple question, but I am still learning. Thanks guys.

Edit: **panel1** and **panel2** are both JScrollPane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a third JPanel that uses whatever layout would work (BorderLayout or BoxLayout come to mind), and add your two JPanels to the third one. Then add the third one to the tabbed pane.

edit: this is a little confusing: "Edit: panel1 and panel2 are both JScrollPane" So these are in fact JScrollPanes, not JPanels? Regardless, my suggestion above still works. :)

Most important though: study how to use layout managers and components such as JPanels etc on the Oracle Swing Tutorials:  [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

```
JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel();
containerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(containerPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
containerPanel.add(panel1);
containerPanel.add(panel2);
pane.add(containerPanel);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know why I didn't think of that. I'm going to try to do this now. (Thanks for the link too)